# Do reserved characters need to be escaped in an Elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch, escaping, query-string

I may not be comprehending this correctly but when using the Query String Query to search my index, it states that reserved or special characters need to be escaped.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters

> The reserved characters are: + - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /

Failing to escape these special characters correctly could lead to a syntax error which prevents your query from running."

Currently my index does not tokenize special characters since I am using just the standard analyzer but I do have both analyzed and not analyzed on all string fields.

So if I have these strings indexed:

```
quick fox
brown fox
```

When i run a query:

```
{
    "query_string" : {
        "query" : "(quick OR brown) AND fox",
    }
}
```

The correct results come back.  But based on the reserved characters documentation should the query with the parentheses "(" and ")" need to be escaped in the query string query?  I am a bit confused on when to escape the reserved characters and when not to in the query?

Does it need to be?:

```
{
    "query_string" : {
        "query" : "\(quick OR brown\) AND fox",
    }
}
```

I know that parentheses are used for grouping so it makes sense not to escape them.  But which reserved characters are always needed to be escaped in Elasticsearch's queries?  Only when the reserved characters are operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reserved characters only need to be escaped if they are not part of the query syntax.

So in `(quick OR brown) AND fox` you don't escape anything.

But if for instance your field contains a reserved character that you want to search on, e.g. your field contains `Hello!` and `!` is a reserved character equivalent to a `NOT` and you want to search for `Hello!`, then your query needs to be like this

```
`Hello\! AND blabla`
      ^^
      ||
escaped reserved char
```

Comment: That's what I thought initially but some of the reserved characters will throw a parsing exception for example: if a query with the search string "etc/elasticsearch", it will throw the exception.  That is why I am not clear what characters need to be escaped for search queries and won't effect the search results.

Comment: In that case you need to escape it like this `etc\/elasticsearch` since the forward slash is part of the value you're querying and not part of the query syntax

Comment: I guess that is what I was trying find out.  Which reserved characters need to be escaped or which ones can just be passed through.

Comment: The rule is simple: 1) escape if the reserved character needs to be part of the value you're searching, 2) don't escape if the reserved character is an integral part of the query syntax

Comment: Thanks Val, that is a very simple rule of course if you knew what is being searched and what is not.  Meaning if the site allows an open ended search functionality and it's just simply a search text box.  A user can type in whatever search term that want, it forces the logic behind the scenes to enforce what is "searchable".  But then it also goes to what the analyzer does with these reserved characters too, does it get indexed or not.  But in the instance of "(" vs "/", how can one determine what is part of the query syntax and what isn't?

Comment: If you provide a search box where users can type in Lucene queries, then it means you're giving them the full power of what can be expressed in Lucene and you're also making the assumption that your users know the Lucene query language. You're basically delegating to them the responsibility of crafting those queries correctly. it's then very hard to know what to escape and what not. I'd suggest you use `simple_query_string` instead which has been created exactly for the purpose of giving users some more power, but which is much more resilient to input errors.

Comment: Thanks Val, I will look into the simple_query_string query instead.